# how to call an object of another class

Tags: android

I have a main class which has edittext box. And i have another class in the same source folder. Now i want to use the text typed in main class accessible to the another class.

any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different approaches:

1) You could store the value in a static variable somewhere globally in your app (when you leave the activity = onPause) - works ok if your app activities run all in the same process, which by default is the case - unless specified differently in your manifest

2) or use the SharedPreferences ([ref. to android dev docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)).

3) If your one activity starts the seconds one right after, you could pass the value as an intent extra ([ref. to android dev docs](http://tinyurl.com/2ultohf)):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, A.class);
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_TEXT_TO_REMEMBER", editText.getText().toString());
startActivity(intent);
```